# How to calculate TF object detection API accuracy over custom dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using TF object detection API to detect object on a custom dataset but when it comes to accuracy I have no idea how to calculate it so,
How to calculate the accuracy of the object detection model over a custom dataset? And find the confident score of the model over the test dataset?
I tried to use eval.py but it is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about training accuracy, validation accuracy or test accuracy? As the names suggest there are 3 different values for accuracy:

- Training accuracy: accuracy of the model on the training set
- Validation accuracy: accuracy of the model on the validation set
- Test accuracy: accuracy of the model on the test set

Training and validation accuracy are outputs of the training, for the test accuracy you need to run the model on the test set.

Did you retrain the model (from a checkpoint, fine tuning...) or did you use the model as you got it? If you have retrained the model you should have training and validation accuracy easily, actually you have those values for each epoch.
If you haven't retrained the model you can only check the test accuracy, given that the test dataset is labelled.

Comment: I retrained a model from a checkpoint, I want to know the test-set accuracy so I would be able to use it for future data! by future data, I meant unseen data that are not training, validation or test data, although we can look at those new data as a test datasets. And I want the accuracy of the model on the test dataset, and I think to have it in average, not per epoch.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033008/how-to-train-and-evaluate-simultaneously-in-object-detection-api) helped me to run eval.py and get mAP value for training data.
Just need to run using CUDA like this:
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="" python3 eval.py --logtostderr  --pipeline_config_path=pre-trained-model/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config  --checkpoint_dir=training/  --eval_dir=eval/